# How can I input to a file directly from the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, files, input

Other than bringing up a text editor, is there a way I can input text in a linux terminal directly to a file?  (then enter a control code such as ctrl-c, to end the input)

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this...  I am SSH'd to a server with Docker, and running bash inside a container, so that I can test some stuff, I just want to be able to paste a small script in my terminal window, and have that output to a file inside the container's shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a useful use of `cat`: provide input on stdin

```
cat > filename
enter text
hit Ctrl-D to stop
```

or use a [heredoc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)

```
cat > filename << END
enter text
provide the terminating word to stop
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was something like this, couldn't for the life of me remember, and searching google was just about impossible to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cat > some_file
```

to write into the file `some_file`. End your input with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`echo "Hello" > test.txt`

This will OVERWRITE "hello" in to the test file. If the file did not exist it will create it

`echo "Hello2" >> test.txt`

This will add a NEW line in the file with hello2

Comment: I actually needed to paste more than would fit on a line to the text... I wanted to paste a file into my terminal window, and have it save to a file where the terminal was connected.